# Changing lat long to UTM in csv using Save As in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv

I have tried to change the lat long to UTM using "Save As" in QGIS 2.18.13 and tried again in QGIS 3.0.1, I cannot get it to work.

I have a .csv file in the form

> id Base_latitude   Base_longitude
>   L001   -33.913912  150.862774
>   L002   -33.942172  150.857137
>   L003   -34.055889  150.747552

I add it to QGIS with the CRS set to ESPGS:4326 - WGS 84
[image: Image of Layer Properties showing CRS as ESPGS:4326 - WGS 84]

I then right click on the layer, click "Save As" and set the CRS to ESPG:32756 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 56S and save it as a new .csv.

[image: Image of Save vector Layer As screen]

According to the tutorials and previous stackexchange answers this should produce a .csv file in the form

> X      Y      id   Base_latitude   Base_longitude
>   number number L001 -33.913912  150.862774
>   number number L002 -33.942172  150.857137
>   number number L003 -34.055889  150.747552

Instead the output .csv is exactly the same as the input. Am I missing a step? I've tried in two different QGIS versions (2.18.13 and 3.0.1) so I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: Are you sure that when you added the .csv file, QGIS acctually read the geometry definition as points and not as attribute table only? Could you zoom to the points? Be aware that drag&drop does not propt you to the window to configurate the geometry definition

Comment: @Marco, I can "Zoom to Layer" and see all the points spread out in the center work space. I'm 99% sure that means it's reading the geometry definition as points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never saved a .csv file before, I am always reading them only. So I had to test your problem.

I realized that the default option in the `Geometry` in the `Layer Options` produce no geometry in the output file.

[image]

So, you need to instruct the command saying it how you want the geometry output as in the picture below.

[image]